# boost::multi_index_container with random_access and ordered_unique

Tags: c++, boost, random-access, multi-index

I have a problem getting `boost::multi_index_container` work with random-access and with orderd_unique at the same time. (I'm sorry for the lengthly question, but I think I should use an example..)

Here an example: Suppose I want to produce N objects in a factory and for each object I have a demand to fulfill (this demand is known at creation of the multi-index).
Well, within my algorithm I get intermediate results, which I store in the following class:

```
class intermediate_result
{
private:
    std::vector<int>   parts;     // which parts are produced
    int                used_time; // how long did it take to produce

    ValueType          max_value; // how much is it worth
};
```

The vector `parts` descibes, which objects are produced (its length is N and it is lexicographically smaller then my coresp demand-vector!) - for each such vector I know the used_time as well. Additionally I get a value for this vector of produced objects.

I got another constraint so that I can't produce every object - my algorithm needs to store several `intermediate_result`-objects in a data-structure. And here `boost::multi_index_container` is used, because the pair of `parts` and `used_time` describes a unique `intermediate_result` (and it should be unique in my data-structure) but the `max_value` is another index I'll have to consider, because my algorithm always needs the `intermediate_result` with the highest `max_value`.

So I tried to use `boost::multi_index_container` with `ordered_unique<>` for my "parts&used_time-pair" and `ordered_non_unique<>` for my `max_value` (different `intermediate_result`-objects may have the same value).

The problem is: the predicate, which is needed to decide which "parts&used_time-pair" is smaller, uses `std::lexicographical_compare` on my `parts`-vector and hence is very slow for many `intermediate_result`-objects.
But there would be a solution: my demand for each object isn't that high, therefore I could store on each **possible** parts-vector the intermediate results uniquely by its `used_time`.

For example: if I have a demand-vector `( 2 , 3 , 1)` then I need a data-structure which stores `(2+1)*(3+1)*(1+1)=24` possible parts-vectors and on each such entry the different used_times, which have to be unique! (storing the smallest time is insufficient - for example: if my additional constraint is: to meet a given time exactly for production)

But how do I combine a `random_access<>`-index with an `ordered_unique<>`-index?
([Example11](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example11) didn't help me on this one..)

Comment: ohh, I forgot to mention: The predicate for the uniqueness of the "parts&used_time-pair" is not faster if I test the used_time before the vector. Additionally I tried to use `hashed_unique<>` instead of `ordered_unique<>` - but I had to push the vector and the used_time in a string to be able to use the hash (the resulting multi_index was slower).  
Is there a better way to use the hash or use an own random_access data-structure (which guarantees uniqueness) linked with the other ordering index (for max_value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I had to use an own answer to write code-blocks - sorry!)

The `composite_key` with `used_time` and `parts` (as Kirill V. Lyadvinsky suggested) is basically what I've already implemented. I want to get rid of the lexicographical compare of the `parts`-vector.

Suppose I've stored the needed_demand somehow then I could write a simple function, which returns the correct index within a random-access data-structure like that:

```
int get_index(intermediate_result &input_result) const
{
    int ret_value  = 0;
    int index_part = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<needed_demand.size();++i)
    {
        ret_value  += input_result.get_part(i) * index_part;
        index_part *= (needed_demand.get_part(i) + 1);
    }
}
```

Obviously this can be implemented more efficiently and this is not the only possible index ordering for the needed demand. But let's suppose this function exists as a member-function of `intermediate_result`! Is it possible to write something like this to prevent `lexicographical_compare` ?

```
indexed_by<
  random_access< >,      
  ordered_unique< 
    composite_key< 
      intermediate_result,
      member<intermediate_result, int, &intermediate_result::used_time>,
      const_mem_fun<intermediate_result,int,&intermediate_result::get_index>
    >
  >
>
```

If this is possible and I initialized the multi-index with all possible `parts`-vectors (i.e. in my comment above I would've pushed 24 empty maps in my data-structure), does this find the right entry for a given `intermediate_result` in constant time (after computing the correct index with `get_index`) ?
I have to ask this, because I don't quite see, how the `random_access<>` index is linked with the `ordered_unique<>` index..

But thank you for your answers so far!!

Comment: Remove `random_access` and replace `ordered_unique` with `hashed_unique`. You'll be able to use `find` function to find element identified be `used_time`/`get_index` pair. Or you could use `equal_range` to find set of elements with specified `used_time`.

Comment: You could use any index independently. To find element by specified index you should write `container.get<1>().find`, where 1 is an index number. 0 is used by default (e.g. `container.find`).

Comment: If you will remove `random_access` index then you'll write `container.find` or `container.equal_range`.

Comment: It is nice to use hashed_unique, but it is not faster. :-( Lets make a bold assumption: Suppose `used_time` is limited by a constant `max_time`. Then I could easily extend the `get_index` function to return a unique integer (better: std::size_t) for each `used_time`/`get_index` pair. Therefore: if I initialize my data-structure with all such possible integers as a `random_access<>` index and store on each entry the `max_value` (as a second `ordered_not_unique<>` index), then I should be able to work with it really fast (insert/find/update in constant time for a given unique `get_index` result)

Comment: The problem with this approach is (of course) that I'll have to use way more memory for this, because the `max_time` could be very high (in relation to the `needed_demand` entires). Additionally most of those entries will not get a useful `intermediate_result`, because the algorithm doesn't provide an `intermediate_result` for most possible `used_times`.

Comment: In my detour with that extended `get_index` function I explicitly produced unique integers resulting in a `random_access<>` index which is unique at the same time! Isn't there a way to tell the multi-index that I do have a `random_access` index, but that it is unique by a given compare-function (or something like that) ? If that would be possible, then I wouldn't need that much memory...

Answer (score 2):

To use two indices you could write the following:

```
indexed_by<
  random_access< >,      
  ordered_unique< 
    composite_key< 
      intermediate_result,
      member<intermediate_result, int, &intermediate_result::used_time>,
      member<intermediate_result, std::vector<int>, &intermediate_result::parts>
    >
  >
>
```

You could use `composite_key` for comparing `used_time` at first and `vector` only if necessary. Besides that, keep in mind that you could use member function as index.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but would this prohibit having the same `used_time` for different `parts`-vectors? I mean: only the pair of vector and used_time is supposed to be unique (not the time itself)

Comment: Use `composite_key` then. Updated my answer.

Comment: Just as an example: I could write an own data-structure which has 24 entries for every possible parts-vector (for the example above) and in each entry there is a `std::map<used_time , max_value>`. Those maps can be empty (if no such intermediate result was found). But the used_time for a given parts-vector is unique. BUT I have to search for the highest max_value as well! So I wanted to build this kind of data-structure with the random-access index of the multi_index_container...
(ohh, just read your comment on `composite_key` - I'll look into that - thanks!!)

Comment: As you suggested, this approach would be better with a member function which returns a (unique) index. With this I can prevent the use of `lexicographical_compare` for the vector of integers. Thank you! But as I mentioned in my answer/question: Then I don't really need the `random_access<>` index, because I didn't force uniqueness for this index or am I missing something? I would like the data-structure to use constant-time lookup through the `get_index` function (especially when I insert a new element, which has to be checked for uniqueness). Is there a way to do this with multi-index?