# Boost Multi-Index : Composite key of vector and int for hashed indices

Tags: c++, boost, vector, multi-index

as I've just learned in [in my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699704/boostmultiindexcontainer-with-randomaccess-and-orderedunique), I could use a `composite_key` for a struct, which has a `std::vector` and an integer. Now my question is: Can I use this somehow to work with hashed_indecies?

Here an example similar to [THIS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html#composite_keys_hash):

```
struct unique_property
{
  //the pair of int and std::vector<int> shall be unique
  int my_int;
  std::vector<int>  my_vec;
};

typedef multi_index_container<
  unique_property,
  indexed_by<
    hashed_unique< // indexed by my_int and every entry of my_vec
      composite_key<
        street_entry,
        member<unique_property,int,&unique_property::my_int>,
        member<unique_property,std::vector<int>,&unique_property::my_vec>
      >
    >,
    random_access< >
  >
> property_locator;
```

The problem is (of course) that a `std::vector<int>` is no suitable hash-key. Can I put this code in an elegant wrapper (or something like that), to produce a hash-key from every entry of `my_vec` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code snippet from your suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699704/boostmultiindexcontainer-with-randomaccess-and-orderedunique/1700899#1700899). It should work. I've added my comments there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want vector to be hashable, you can just write a `hash<vector<int> >` function in `namespace std`, making it hash however you please (hint: you might be able to get away with hashing only the first few elements in some applications).  This should make `std::hash_set<vector<int> >` work, and I think your more complex container as well.