# Boost Multi-Index with hashed_unique_index produces compiler error

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, hash, multi-index

I learned in [THIS THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701022/boost-multi-index-composite-key-of-vector-and-int-for-hashed-indices) how a `hashed_unique<>` index can be used with a `composite_key` using an int and a `std::vector<int>`. But unfortunately the following code produces quite an error message:

`1> boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp(439) : error C2784: 'size_t .. composite_key_hash<...>::operator ()(const boost::tuples::tuple<...> &) const' :`**could not deduce template argument**`for 'const boost::tuples::tuple<...> &' from 'const unique_property'`

Here the code, does anyone know whats wrong? :-?

```
    #include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
    #include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
    #include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
    #include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
    #include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>

    #include <vector>

    using boost::multi_index_container;
    using namespace boost::multi_index;


    class unique_property
    {
    private:
      int  my_value;

      //the pair of int and std::vector<int> shall be unique
      int my_int;
      std::vector<int>  my_vec;

    public:
        //stupid ctor (my_values are unique as well, but thats not the point here)
        unique_property(int input_value)
        : my_value(input_value), my_int(10), my_vec(my_int,my_value)
        {}

        int get_int() const {return my_int;}
        const std::vector<int> & get_vec() const {return my_vec;}
    };



    struct hugo{};



    typedef multi_index_container<
      unique_property,
      indexed_by<
        hashed_unique< tag<hugo> ,// indexed by my_int and every entry of my_vec
          composite_key< 
            unique_property,
            const_mem_fun<unique_property,int,&unique_property::get_int >,
            const_mem_fun<unique_property,
                          const std::vector<int> &,&unique_property::get_vec >
          >
        >,
        random_access< >
      >
    > property_locator;

    // for brevity
    typedef property_locator::index<hugo>::type ProbLocByHugo;


    void dummy_test()
    {
        property_locator local_data_structure;
        unique_property tempy(5);

        ProbLocByHugo::iterator pos = local_data_structure.get<hugo>().find(tempy);

        //if (pos == local_data_structure.get<hugo>().end() )
        //    local_data_structure.insert(tempy);
        //else
        //{
        //    local_data_structure.get<hugo>().replace(pos,tempy);
        //}
    }
```

The complete error messages are:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: buggy, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>Compiling...
    1>c:\myPath\boost_1_37_0\include\boost-1_37\boost\multi_index\hashed_index.hpp(439) : error C2784: 'size_t boost::multi_index::composite_key_hash<Hash0,Hash1,Hash2,Hash3,Hash4,Hash5,Hash6,Hash7,Hash8,Hash9>::operator ()(const boost::tuples::tuple<Value0,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Value6,Value7,Value8,Value9> &) const' : could not deduce template argument for 'const boost::tuples::tuple<Value0,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Value6,Value7,Value8,Value9> &' from 'const unique_property'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            Hash0=boost::hash<int>,
    1>            Hash1=boost::hash<const std::vector<int>>,
    1>            Hash2=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash3=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash4=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash5=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash6=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash7=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash8=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash9=boost::tuples::null_type
    1>        ]
    1>        c:\myPath\boost_1_37_0\include\boost-1_37\boost\multi_index\composite_key.hpp(1099) : see declaration of 'boost::multi_index::composite_key_hash<Hash0,Hash1,Hash2,Hash3,Hash4,Hash5,Hash6,Hash7,Hash8,Hash9>::operator ()'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            Hash0=boost::hash<int>,
    1>            Hash1=boost::hash<const std::vector<int>>,
    1>            Hash2=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash3=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash4=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash5=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash6=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash7=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash8=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash9=boost::tuples::null_type
    1>        ]
    1>        c:\myPath\boost_1_37_0\include\boost-1_37\boost\multi_index\hashed_index.hpp(429) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_iterator<Node,BucketArray> boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index<KeyFromValue,Hash,Pred,SuperMeta,TagList,Category>::find<CompatibleKey,boost::hash<T>,std::equal_to<_Ty>>(const CompatibleKey &,const CompatibleHash &,const CompatiblePred &) const' being compiled
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            Node=boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::random_access_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<unique_property,std::allocator<unique_property>>>>,
    1>            BucketArray=boost::multi_index::detail::bucket_array<std::allocator<unique_property>>,
    1>            KeyFromValue=boost::multi_index::composite_key<unique_property,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,int,unique_property::get_int>,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,const std::vector<int> &,unique_property::get_vec>>,
    1>            Hash=boost::hash<boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<boost::multi_index::composite_key<unique_property,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,int,unique_property::get_int>,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,const std::vector<int> &,unique_property::get_vec>>>>,
    1>            Pred=std::equal_to<boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<boost::multi_index::composite_key<unique_property,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,int,unique_property::get_int>,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,const std::vector<int> &,unique_property::get_vec>>>>,
    1>            SuperMeta=boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1,unique_property,boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<hugo>,boost::multi_index::composite_key<unique_property,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,int,unique_property::get_int>,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,const std::vector<int> &,unique_property::get_vec>>>,boost::multi_index::random_access<>>,std::allocator<unique_property>>,
    1>            TagList=boost::mpl::vector1<hugo>,
    1>            Category=boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_unique_tag,
    1>            CompatibleKey=unique_property,
    1>            T=boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<boost::multi_index::composite_key<unique_property,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,int,unique_property::get_int>,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,const std::vector<int> &,unique_property::get_vec>>>,
    1>            _Ty=boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<boost::multi_index::composite_key<unique_property,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,int,unique_property::get_int>,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,const std::vector<int> &,unique_property::get_vec>>>,
    1>            CompatibleHash=boost::hash<boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<boost::multi_index::composite_key<unique_property,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,int,unique_property::get_int>,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,const std::vector<int> &,unique_property::get_vec>>>>,
    1>            CompatiblePred=std::equal_to<boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<boost::multi_index::composite_key<unique_property,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,int,unique_property::get_int>,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,const std::vector<int> &,unique_property::get_vec>>>>
    1>        ]
    1>        c:\documents and settings\amenge.dedekind\desktop\ggt_test\mem_rw_test.cpp(886) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_iterator<Node,BucketArray> boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index<KeyFromValue,Hash,Pred,SuperMeta,TagList,Category>::find<unique_property>(const CompatibleKey &) const' being compiled
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            Node=boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::random_access_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<unique_property,std::allocator<unique_property>>>>,
    1>            BucketArray=boost::multi_index::detail::bucket_array<std::allocator<unique_property>>,
    1>            KeyFromValue=boost::multi_index::composite_key<unique_property,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,int,unique_property::get_int>,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,const std::vector<int> &,unique_property::get_vec>>,
    1>            Hash=boost::hash<boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<boost::multi_index::composite_key<unique_property,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,int,unique_property::get_int>,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,const std::vector<int> &,unique_property::get_vec>>>>,
    1>            Pred=std::equal_to<boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<boost::multi_index::composite_key<unique_property,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,int,unique_property::get_int>,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,const std::vector<int> &,unique_property::get_vec>>>>,
    1>            SuperMeta=boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1,unique_property,boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<hugo>,boost::multi_index::composite_key<unique_property,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,int,unique_property::get_int>,boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<unique_property,const std::vector<int> &,unique_property::get_vec>>>,boost::multi_index::random_access<>>,std::allocator<unique_property>>,
    1>            TagList=boost::mpl::vector1<hugo>,
    1>            Category=boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_unique_tag,
    1>            CompatibleKey=unique_property
    1>        ]
    1>c:\myPath\boost_1_37_0\include\boost-1_37\boost\multi_index\hashed_index.hpp(439) : error C2784: 'size_t boost::multi_index::composite_key_hash<Hash0,Hash1,Hash2,Hash3,Hash4,Hash5,Hash6,Hash7,Hash8,Hash9>::operator ()(const boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<CompositeKey1> &) const' : could not deduce template argument for 'const boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<CompositeKey1> &' from 'const unique_property'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            Hash0=boost::hash<int>,
    1>            Hash1=boost::hash<const std::vector<int>>,
    1>            Hash2=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash3=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash4=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash5=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash6=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash7=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash8=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash9=boost::tuples::null_type
    1>        ]
    1>        c:\myPath\boost_1_37_0\include\boost-1_37\boost\multi_index\composite_key.hpp(1083) : see declaration of 'boost::multi_index::composite_key_hash<Hash0,Hash1,Hash2,Hash3,Hash4,Hash5,Hash6,Hash7,Hash8,Hash9>::operator ()'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            Hash0=boost::hash<int>,
    1>            Hash1=boost::hash<const std::vector<int>>,
    1>            Hash2=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash3=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash4=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash5=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash6=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash7=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash8=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Hash9=boost::tuples::null_type
    1>        ]
    1>c:\myPath\boost_1_37_0\include\boost-1_37\boost\multi_index\hashed_index.hpp(443) : error C2784: 'bool boost::multi_index::composite_key_equal_to<Pred0,Pred1,Pred2,Pred3,Pred4,Pred5,Pred6,Pred7,Pred8,Pred9>::operator ()(const boost::tuples::tuple<Value0,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Value6,Value7,Value8,Value9> &,const boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<CompositeKey> &) const' : could not deduce template argument for 'const boost::tuples::tuple<Value0,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Value6,Value7,Value8,Value9> &' from 'const unique_property'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            Pred0=std::equal_to<int>,
    1>            Pred1=std::equal_to<const std::vector<int>>,
    1>            Pred2=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred3=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred4=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred5=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred6=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred7=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred8=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred9=boost::tuples::null_type
    1>        ]
    1>        c:\myPath\boost_1_37_0\include\boost-1_37\boost\multi_index\composite_key.hpp(914) : see declaration of 'boost::multi_index::composite_key_equal_to<Pred0,Pred1,Pred2,Pred3,Pred4,Pred5,Pred6,Pred7,Pred8,Pred9>::operator ()'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            Pred0=std::equal_to<int>,
    1>            Pred1=std::equal_to<const std::vector<int>>,
    1>            Pred2=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred3=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred4=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred5=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred6=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred7=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred8=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred9=boost::tuples::null_type
    1>        ]
    1>c:\myPath\boost_1_37_0\include\boost-1_37\boost\multi_index\hashed_index.hpp(443) : error C2784: 'bool boost::multi_index::composite_key_equal_to<Pred0,Pred1,Pred2,Pred3,Pred4,Pred5,Pred6,Pred7,Pred8,Pred9>::operator ()(const boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<CompositeKey1> &,const boost::tuples::tuple<Value0,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Value6,Value7,Value8,Value9> &) const' : could not deduce template argument for 'const boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<CompositeKey1> &' from 'const unique_property'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            Pred0=std::equal_to<int>,
    1>            Pred1=std::equal_to<const std::vector<int>>,
    1>            Pred2=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred3=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred4=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred5=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred6=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred7=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred8=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred9=boost::tuples::null_type
    1>        ]
    1>        c:\myPath\boost_1_37_0\include\boost-1_37\boost\multi_index\composite_key.hpp(889) : see declaration of 'boost::multi_index::composite_key_equal_to<Pred0,Pred1,Pred2,Pred3,Pred4,Pred5,Pred6,Pred7,Pred8,Pred9>::operator ()'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            Pred0=std::equal_to<int>,
    1>            Pred1=std::equal_to<const std::vector<int>>,
    1>            Pred2=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred3=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred4=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred5=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred6=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred7=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred8=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred9=boost::tuples::null_type
    1>        ]
    1>c:\myPath\boost_1_37_0\include\boost-1_37\boost\multi_index\hashed_index.hpp(443) : error C2784: 'bool boost::multi_index::composite_key_equal_to<Pred0,Pred1,Pred2,Pred3,Pred4,Pred5,Pred6,Pred7,Pred8,Pred9>::operator ()(const boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<CompositeKey1> &,const boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<CompositeKey2> &) const' : could not deduce template argument for 'const boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<CompositeKey1> &' from 'const unique_property'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            Pred0=std::equal_to<int>,
    1>            Pred1=std::equal_to<const std::vector<int>>,
    1>            Pred2=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred3=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred4=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred5=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred6=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred7=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred8=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred9=boost::tuples::null_type
    1>        ]
    1>        c:\myPath\boost_1_37_0\include\boost-1_37\boost\multi_index\composite_key.hpp(859) : see declaration of 'boost::multi_index::composite_key_equal_to<Pred0,Pred1,Pred2,Pred3,Pred4,Pred5,Pred6,Pred7,Pred8,Pred9>::operator ()'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            Pred0=std::equal_to<int>,
    1>            Pred1=std::equal_to<const std::vector<int>>,
    1>            Pred2=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred3=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred4=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred5=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred6=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred7=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred8=boost::tuples::null_type,
    1>            Pred9=boost::tuples::null_type
    1>        ]
```

Comment: Could you indicate in your code snippet which line produces the error exactly... not sure it'll help much but it would still be easier.

Comment: Also, could you give the full stack of error and the version of Boost you actually use ? The boost header has changed since.

Comment: Hello an thank you for your suggestions. I added the complete error messages and changed the call a little (only one line is invoked after creation of objects). But I think that I forgot some kind of parameter or something like that..
As you'll see, I'm using boost version 1.37

Comment: As far as I can tell, the problem stems from `ProbLocByHugo::iterator pos = local_data_structure.get<hugo>().find(tempy);` as the error referenced (line 439) corresponds to the invocation of `find`. Now I can look for the cause :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay Let's get working (comments just allow so much).

The problem stems from the invocation of the `find` method.

The template elected is:

```
template<
  typename CompatibleKey,typename CompatibleHash,typename CompatiblePred
>
iterator find(const CompatibleKey& k,
              const CompatibleHash& hash,
              const CompatiblePred& eq) const;
```

With:

```
KeyFromValue = composite_key<...>
CompatibleKey = unique_property
CompatibleHash = boost::hash<KeyFromValue>
CompatiblePred = equal_to<KeyFromValue>
```

Apparently, the invocation `hash(k)` inside the `find` method fails for the reason cited (could not deduce...), this methods itself invokes:

```
template<BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CK_ENUM_PARAMS(typename Value)>
std::size_t operator()(const tuple<BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CK_ENUM_PARAMS(Value)>& x)const
```

(Don't be afraid by the macro, it's just some magic Boost.Preprocessor to enumerate the `Value` from 0 to 9)

Now, from this we can see that the problem is that we try to build `tuple<Value0, Value1, ..., Value9>` from `CompatibleKey` ie `unique_property` and it does not work.

I think you should try:

```
ProbLocByHugo::iterator pos =
  local_data_structure.get<hugo>().find(boost::make_tuple(tempy));
```

Here is the example of `composite_key` from [Boost][1]:

```
file_system_by_name::iterator it=fs.find(
  boost::make_tuple(current_dir,dir));

boost::tie(it0,it1)=fs_by_size.equal_range(
    boost::make_tuple(current_dir));
```

As you can see, any invocation of key usage leads to `make_tuple`.

You could avoid this by providing the right conversion operator for your `unique_property` class.

```
operator boost::tuple< int, std::vector<int> const& >() const
  { return boost::make_tuple(my_int, cref(my_vec)); }
```

Or perhaps a variation...

I have to admit that I am a bit disappointed by this requirement, I would have expected that `find` would work seemlessly.

[1] http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/multi_index/example/composite_keys.cpp

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your time and your solution! I tried your first approach but it didn't work right away. After thinking about your second suggestion I tried the following call:  
`ProbLocByHugo::iterator pos = local_data_structure.get<hugo>().find(boost::make_tuple(tempy.get_int(),tempy.get_vec()));` 

And that did the trick! Thank you again for your much appreciated help!! Have a great day!

Comment: You're welcome, I still don't get why this is not automatic anyway, as you have given the extraction method in template parameter...

Answer (score 3):

Matthieu hints at the problem but probably does not expclicitly pinpoint it: find() expects a *key* or a *compatible key* and you're passing a whole *element*. How do you extract the key from `tempy`? There are two ways:

- Construct a compatible tuple as Matthieu shows.
- Each index provides a `key_extractor()` member function that returns a copy of the internal key extractor (here, a value of `composite_key<...>`) for you to use:

`ProbLocByHugo::iterator pos = local_data_structure.get<hugo>().find(
      local_data_structure.get<hugo>().key_extractor()(tempy));`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your additional information. But I don't see, how boost is not able to get these information by itself. I mean: I'm saying in the definition of the `composite_key` how to get the necessary members of an element/object of type `unique_property`, why do I have to do it again in any find-statement? On the other hand it is quite useful to be able to put just the necessary parts in a find-statement (if a complete element/object is expensive to build). But I think both ways wouldn't be that hard to implement... But thanks again for your info!

Comment: I *could* add an overload of `find()` that takes whole elements rather than keys but I prefer to keep it terse because
this is how STL containers work, they expect keys, not whole elements (cf. `std::map`), and because in some pathological cases, such overload would result in a problem: consider the following element type:

`struct element
{
  const element& key(){return *k;};
  ...
private:
  element* k;
};`

and a `multi_index_container` with `const_mem_fun<element,const element&,&element::key>` What happens if you now say:

`element x=...;
c.find(x);`

Left as an exercise for the reader :-)